# Why does Enum.ToString() not return the correct enum name?

Tags: c#, .net, enums

I'm working with an external library that has an enum. There are some members of this enum that, when you call `ToString()` on them, return the name of a different member of the enum.

```
Console.WriteLine("TOKEN_RIGHT = {0}", Tokens.TOKEN_RIGHT.ToString());  //prints TOKEN_OUTER
Console.WriteLine("TOKEN_FROM = {0}", Tokens.TOKEN_FROM.ToString());  //prints TOKEN_FROM
Console.WriteLine("TOKEN_OUTER = {0}", Tokens.TOKEN_OUTER.ToString());  //prints TOKEN_FULL
```

I know that when two enum members have the same numerical value, you can get behavior like this, but I know, from decompilation and checking the values at run-time, that each member in the enum has a unique value.

Here's a snippet of the enum's definition (generated by [dotPeek](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/)):

```
public enum Tokens
{

    TOKEN_OR = 134,
    TOKEN_AND = 135,
    TOKEN_NOT = 136,
    TOKEN_DOUBLECOLON = 137,
    TOKEN_ELSE = 138,
    TOKEN_WITH = 139,
    TOKEN_WITH_CHECK = 140,
    TOKEN_GRANT = 141,
    TOKEN_CREATE = 142,
    TOKEN_DENY = 143,
    TOKEN_DROP = 144,
    TOKEN_ADD = 145,
    TOKEN_SET = 146,
    TOKEN_REVOKE = 147,
    TOKEN_CROSS = 148,
    TOKEN_FULL = 149,
    TOKEN_INNER = 150,
    TOKEN_OUTER = 151,
    TOKEN_LEFT = 152,
    TOKEN_RIGHT = 153,
    TOKEN_UNION = 154,
    TOKEN_JOIN = 155,
    TOKEN_PIVOT = 156,
    TOKEN_UNPIVOT = 157,
    TOKEN_FROM = 242,
}
```

Why is this happening? Is there something I'm doing wrong, or is this just another one of those fun quirks of enums in .NET? If the latter, is there a workaround for it?

(For what it's worth, `Tokens` is part of of the [Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlParser.Parser](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.sqlparser.parser.aspx) namespace in .NET.)

Comment: What happens if you set a breakpoint, then evaluate the `.ToString` expressions in the Immediate window?

Comment: Is that a complete copy paste?  The extra , at the end does not look right to me

Comment: @Blam, no it's not complete; as stated, it's just a snippet.

Comment: @Dai, that's the really weird part, in the Immediate window, the values return as expected. (I forgot to mention that in the initial post.)

Comment: There is no TOKEN_FROM in the enum list (code from snippet i know) and I get testing this in dotnetfiddle -> TOKEN_OUTER = TOKEN_OUTER

Comment: I'm thinking you may be looking at two different versions of the assembly. Your code (at design time) may be referencing a newer version (since you're able to use `TOKEN_FROM` yet when you inspect the DLL with dotPeek, it's not there) but perhaps the assembly loaded at runtime is an older version with different _underlying values_ thus mismatching the names.

Comment: please post the whole entire 'Token' enum, its possible some of the values could be `&` flagged

Comment: Very easy way to find out whether there are duplicates you can do: add a switch statement with `Tokens`, let VS generate switch cases for you. Then compile. If duplicates are there compiler won't let you to compile.

Comment: @Blam, as trivia, that trailing comma is valid in C# enums. I use that myself so I don't have to worry about an uncomma-d value hanging out in the middle.

Comment: I just ran your code against versions 11 and 12 of `Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlParser` and I received the expected values. I'm thinking the same as Chris Sinclair. Maybe run a Clean Solution.

Comment: You know that is deprecated?  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.sqlparser.parser.tokens(v=sql.110).aspx

Comment: @Kunukn, thanks for pointing that out, I did miss that. I've edited it to include it. Blam, I did see that it's not supported, which is why I've changed my actual code to not use it anymore. I would think the question could apply to other enums though. Chris, I will see if there are different reference stepping on each other, thanks!

Comment: @mxmissile, the enum is several hundred lines long, so I posted just a snippet to avoid burying everyone in unnecessary detail. From the decompile, there are no values being `&` flagged.

Comment: Enum.ToString is correct. The mistake is yours. I wanted to point this out because you might mistakenly suspect the BCL to have a bug. This would mislead your efforts.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair, it looks that was it, differing versions of the assembly. (Go ahead and post the answer so I can accept it!)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking at two different versions of the assembly.

Your code (at *design/compile* time) is referencing a newer version (since you're able to use `TOKEN_FROM` yet when you inspect the DLL with dotPeek, it's not there). However, the assembly loaded at *runtime* is an older version with different underlying values thus mismatching the names.

You'll have to investigate how it is you're referencing mismatched DLLs. It could be the installed framework on the executing machine, or perhaps you have projects in the same solution referencing different versions, or perhaps some other reason (it's not possible to determine from the information you have provided).

Once you resolve why you're referencing two different versions and unify it to a single assembly version, the `Enum.ToString()` result should be as you expect it.

Comment: As a quick note, with this particular DLL, the issue came from the fact that Visual Studio uses that DLL (for Database projects), but I was referencing an older version in my project's References.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest probe:

```
Console.WriteLine("TOKEN_RIGHT = {0}", Tokens.TOKEN_RIGHT.ToString("F"));
```

and so on

Comment: Please indent your code so it is formatted properly